# Spring - JdbcTemplate - query with CTE and enumerated rows

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, jdbctemplate

I am trying to create a query which uses CTE constructions. The query looks like this:

```
with data (a, b, c) as (
    values  ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'), ('a2', 'b2', 'c2')
)
select * from data
```

This query is of course simplified, for the sake of keeping it to the point here.

The following works great:

```
@Component
public class QueryTest {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public QueryTest(final DataSource source) {
        template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(source);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void test() {
        MapSqlParameterSource p = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("data", Arrays.asList(
                        new Object[]{"a1", "b1", "c1"},
                        new Object[]{"a2", "b2", "c2"}));
        System.out.println(template.query("with data (a, b, c) as (values :data) select * from data", p, (set, index) -> new Object()));
    }
}
```

However, if I just have one row in my `data` named parameter, it doesn't work:

```
@Component
public class QueryTest {
    private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    public QueryTest(final DataSource source) {
        template = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(source);
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void test() {
        MapSqlParameterSource p = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("data", Arrays.asList(
                        new Object[]{"a1", "b1", "c1"}));
        System.out.println(template.query("with data (a, b, c) as (values :data) select * from data", p, (set, index) -> new Object()));
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 32
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114) ~[postgresql-9.4.1208.jar:9.4.1208]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.5.1.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:629) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Any idea what is going wrong here? Is there a better way to execute these kind of queries?

**update**

I enabled logging in postgres, and it looks like the first query is resolved as:

```
with data (a, b, c) as (values ($1, $2, $3), ($4, $5, $6)) select * from data
```

But the second one is resolved as:

```
with data (a, b, c) as (values $1, $2, $3) select * from data
```

It looks like the surrounding parentheses are lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your use of `Arrays.asList`. When you pass in multiple object arrays you get a list of object arrays. If you only pass in a single object array you get a list of the arrays content rather than a list of a single object array. It interprets the array as separate varargs rather than as one argument. If you print out what `Arrays.asList(new Object[]{"a1", "b1", "c1"})` gives you it will look like: [a1, b1, c1].

For the single array use case, try creating your List using `Collections.singletonList` instead or create an `ArrayList` and then add your data values using `add` method.

`MapSqlParameterSource p = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("data", Collections.singletonList(new Object[]{"a1", "b1", "c1"}));`

Comment: Hehe, you shouldn't, it wasn't obvious what the issue was until I started to poke around and looking at what values were actually past in.